# issue setting parameter to nativeQuery of an entityManager

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager, nativequery

I use an EntityManager to create a nativeQuery. My database is a Oracle database.

In this query:

```
public Map<String, Integer> ricavaDoppioniDiUnaTabellaNSNBroker(String database, String tabella, String colonna) throws PersistenceException {
    Map<String, Integer> doppioniNSN = null;
    try {
        List<Object[]> objList = (List<Object[]>) entityManager.createNativeQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM " +
                                "(SELECT :colonna, COUNT(*) AS occorrenza FROM :tabella t GROUP BY :colonna) a " +
                                "WHERE a.occorrenza > 1")
                .setParameter("colonna", "t." + colonna)
                .setParameter("tabella", database + "." + tabella)
                //.setParameter("colonna", "t." + colonna)
                .getResultList();

        if (objList != null) {
            doppioniNSN = new HashMap<>();
            for (Object[] elem : objList) {
                String nsn_id = elem[0].toString();
                Integer quantity = Integer.valueOf(elem[1].toString());
                doppioniNSN.put(nsn_id, quantity);
            }
        }
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {
        brkLog.error("Errore durante l'esecuzione della query che conta i doppioni. Di seguito parte dello stacktrace...");
        throw e;
    }
    return doppioniNSN;
}
```

I tried to set parameter in order to have a general method for different table, user and column, but i obtain this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2292)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2131)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1163)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
    ... 97 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorE`enter code here`xception: ORA-00903: nome di tabella non valido
```

Where i am doing wrong?

Thanks at all :)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The `query.setParameter()` method only works on where clause. It doesn't work on table names or colums.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. So maybe i have to build a String object of query and than pass it to entityManager?